# Counting number of associations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count how many `conversations` each `user` has closed, and how many `messages` each `user` has written.

A `user` has many `conversations`

A `conversations` has many `messages`

A `message` can belong to a `user`

This is the query I've got some far

```
select a.id, u.display_name, count(c.id) as closed, count(m.id) as replied
from apps a
left join app_users au on au.app_id = a.id
left join users u on u.id = au.user_id
left join conversations c on c.app_id = a.id and c.closed_by_id = u.id
left join messages m on m.conversation_id = c.id and m.user_id = u.id
group by a.id, u.id
order by closed desc
```

It works fine when I'm not joining the messages and just counting the closed conversations. When joining the messages, the `closed` and `replied` column is the exact same number (and is also incorrect for both)

Any ideas?

Comment: may be `count(distinct c.id)` ?

Comment: is there a column that says a message has `closed` or `replied` status?

Comment: Nope, but there's a `closed_at` and a user has replied to a message, if the message's `user_id` matches the user we're counting for

Answer (score 1):

You can do the counting in sub-queries before joining:

```
select a.id, u.display_name, c.closed, m.replied
from apps a
left join app_users au on au.app_id = a.id
left join users u on u.id = au.user_id
left join lateral (
    select id, count(*) as closed
    from conversations
    where closed_by_id = u.id) c on c.app_id = a.id
left join lateral (
    select count(*) as replied
    from messages
    where user_id = u.id) m on m.conversation_id = c.id
order by c.closed desc;
```

Comment: This doesn't group by app_id and display_name. If i add a group for these, then it also want's a group for `closed` and `replied`, but this makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
select a.id, u.display_name,
       count(distinct c.id) as closed, count(distinct m.id) as replied
```

This will work under many circumstances.  But if there are a lot of "closed" and "replied", then the intermediate calculation might be quite large, affecting performance.  If that is an issue, then pre-aggregating the results before the join is the solution.